# Will a paired t-test work for my lab data?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, paired-data

I have a set of 10 samples, each having an unknown concentration of analyte. Each sample is quantitated by method A and method B.  I need to know if the quantitative results from method A differ significantly from method B.  Can I use a paired t-test for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to investigate other ways of doing this like the Bland and Altman plot which is discussed in a long and detailed answer by Stephan Kolassa in [Creating and interpreting Bland-Altman plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99835/creating-and-interpreting-bland-altman-plot) This method has become very widely accepted in health although I do not know about other arenas.

Comment: Thanks, I like the look of these plots and will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Having a sample size of only 10, I would suggest using a non-parametric test such as the Wilcoxon signed-rank test.